# RSolr RequestError Solr Response Severe errors in solr configuration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, solr, sunspot

I was reindexing my model when I suddenly shutdown my mac,
When I try to reindex again using (Model_name).reindex in script/console I encountered an error that I haven't encountered before.

```
RSolr::RequestError: Solr Response: Severe_errors_in_solr_configuration__Check_your_log_files_for_more_detailed_information_on_what_may_be_wrong__If_you_want_solr_to_continue_after_configuration_errors_change____abortOnConfigurationErrorfalseabortOnConfigurationError__in_null___javalangRuntimeException_javaioIOException_read_past_EOF__at_orgapachesolrcoreSolrCoregetSearcherSolrCorejava1068__at_orgapachesolrcoreSolrCoreinitSolrCorejava579__at_orgapachesolrcoreCoreContainer$InitializerinitializeCoreContainerjava137__at_orgapachesolrservletSolrDispatchFilterinitSolrDispatchFilterjava83__at_orgmortbayjettyservletFilterHolderdoStartFilterHolderjava99__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyservletServletHandlerinitializeServletHandlerjava594__at_orgmortbayjettyservletContextstartContextContextjava139__at_orgmortbayjettywebappWebAppContextstartContextWebAppContextjava1218__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerContextHandlerdoStartContextHandlerjava500__at_orgmortbayjettywebappWebAppContextdoStartWebAppContextjava448__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerHandlerCollectiondoStartHandlerCollectionjava147__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerContextHandlerCollectiondoStartContextHandlerCollectionjava161__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerHandlerCollectiondoStartHandlerCollectionjava147__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayjettyhandlerHandlerWrapperdoStartHandlerWrapperjava117__at_orgmortbayjettyServerdoStartServerjava210__at_orgmortbaycomponentAbstractLifeCyclestartAbstractLifeCyclejava40__at_orgmortbayxmlXmlConfigurationmainXmlConfigurationjava929__at_sunreflectNativeMethodAccessorImplinvoke0Native_Method__at_sun
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/connection/requestable.rb:39:in `request'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:34:in `request'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:22:in `update'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rsolr-0.12.1/lib/rsolr/client.rb:76:in `delete_by_query'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.1.0/lib/sunspot/indexer.rb:55:in `remove_all'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.1.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:173:in `remove_all'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.1.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:173:in `each'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.1.0/lib/sunspot/session.rb:173:in `remove_all'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.1.0/lib/sunspot/session_proxy/abstract_session_proxy.rb:11:in `remove_all'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sunspot-1.1.0/lib/sunspot.rb:414:in `remove_all'
        from /Users/cecilleann/Projects/dhire2/vendor/plugins/sunspot_rails-1.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:164:in `solr_remove_all_from_index'
        from /Users/cecilleann/Projects/dhire2/vendor/plugins/sunspot_rails-1.1.0/lib/sunspot/rails/searchable.rb:183:in `reindex'
        from (irb):6
```

Now I haven't been able to fix the error. Please help me. I can't move one.
Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Just as the exception says, your config is invalid. Post it so we can diagnose it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the index folder got corrupted and solr achieved a "deadlock" situation, there's nothing wrong with the solr configuration.
Here's what I've done:

- I erased the solr index folder.
- Changed the following attribute in solrconfig.xml to false:

  ```
    <abortOnConfigurationError>false</abortOnConfigurationError>
  ```
- restart solr if running
- reindexed solr;
- set the abortOnConfigurationError attribute to the original value;
- reindexed again just to be sure that having `abortOnConfigurationError=false` doesn't made me got an erroneous index.

Answer (score 5):

Check running process to validate where tmp file is pointing to then stop the sunspot-solr process and finally delete that tmp file.

for instance:

```
ps -ef | grep sunspot
ps -ef | grep solr
501 53845     1   0   0:00.42 ??         0:02.99 /usr/bin/java 
-Dsolr.data.dir=/var/folders/QJ/QJJ4EWSXEpOEtXE8SN7iS++++TI/-Tmp- 
-Dsolr.solr.home=/Users/aldonievas/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/sunspot-1.1.0/solr/solr 
-jar start.jar
```

so you should delete file `/var/folders/QJ/QJJ4EWSXEpOEtXE8SN7iS++++TI/-Tmp-`

then start the process again. it should work.

Comment: Can't delete a -Tmp- file because it's just a symlink. Unlink it you mean or delete the entire directory?

Comment: @Trip just the file not the entire directory. do you have sudo ?

Comment: Ah, will do next time. It was on my local, and if I just reboot; that solves the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Ha worked! Awesome! For those that might get caught on a little error, you have to delete it by typing this : `rm -rf ./-Tmp-/`